# Why do my updates not work?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I am new to GAE, and to JDO, I am getting stuck with how to update data.

Using the code below, if I do a `getAll()`, then a `get()` on an object, then alter an attribute for that object returned by get(), then a `getAll()`, the second call to `getAll()` returns the original un-altered object.

I tried doing a flush() but that doesn't seem to help. If I restart jetty, the data is not persisted.

```
public class Notes {

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Note> getAll() {
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.instance().getPersistenceManager();

    Query query = pm.newQuery("select from com.uptecs.google1.model.Note order by subject");
    return (List<Note>) query.execute();
}

public void add(Note note) {
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.instance().getPersistenceManager();
    pm.makePersistent(note);
    pm.flush();
}

public Note get(long id) {
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.instance().getPersistenceManager();
    return (Note)pm.getObjectById(Note.class, id);
}

public void update(Note note) {
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.instance().getPersistenceManager();
    pm.flush(); 
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a good overview look at these articles:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-gaej1/
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-gaej2/index.html
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-gaej3.html

2 and 3 are most relevant.

```
public void add(Note note) {
    PersistenceManager pm = getPersistenceManagerFactory()
            .getPersistenceManager();
    try {
        pm.makePersistent(note);
    } finally {
        pm.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's so weird that part 3's link is formatted differently, and doesn't work in a format like the other two... good articles though!

Comment: I clearly misread something in the Google documentation, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the AppEngine [Getting Started Guide](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine.html)? They have a pretty extensive guide on [using the JDO API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/).

Sounds like you aren't [calling close() after modifying](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/creatinggettinganddeletingdata.html#Updating_an_Object) the persistent object.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with JDO but don't you have to commit() or save() your data before flush? I think only these statements will persist in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps actually closing your PersistenceManagers may help (never mind the memory utilisation reasons!)